# Need to capture if xaml page is idle for 2 minutes

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

I am new to windows app development. I am currently working on an Universal App using c# and XAML, which has 4 pages, first page being a welcome page. I have to check on other 3 pages (other than welcome page) that if the page is idle for last 2 minutes then I have to reload the welcome page, forcing used to start from the beginning. I did research on this on google, but couldn't find anything helpful. Hope someone from stack overflow community can direct in right direction.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the welcome page for a login? If you are requiring the user to login to view the extra pages you will also have to handle when the app is in the background. In app.xaml.cs, subscribe to the corewindowvisibilitychanged event. Save a time stamp and now you can check how long the app has been in the background and navigate to the welcome page in the I launched event. 
To implement an idle timer you should look at the I launched event where the root frame is created. Subscribe to the pointer moved event in the maimwindow, or use a base page for the similar three pages in your app. When pointer moves, start a dispatcher timer that will be your ticking time bomb for when the navigation occurs. If the pointer moved event happens again, call dispatcher timer.stop, null it out and start a new one. You may also want to subscribe to keyboard events too. 
Don't forget to subscribe to pointer moved from the c#, so you can use the overload to handle all events, even when an originating source has already handled it. :)

Comment: Hi ClevelandBuckeye, 

Thanks for your response. There is no login page on this app, the app is open for any user. User will have to tab/click "Start" button on welcome page to initiate their session. This session will terminates when there is no activity from user for 2 minutes or if user choose to terminate session by tabbing/clicking "Finish" button available on other 3 pages. 

Also, this app will be installed on tablet dedicated for this app. In another words this app will always be running on the tablet, and app's welcome page will be ON all the time if tablet is in idle state.